# How to make Cloud Scheduler to run on specific dates?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have written a script on cloud run.. And would like to execute it twice or thrice some days in the future.

Lets say today is 19/Jan/2023... Now how do I set Cloud Scheduler to run my cloud run on only 13/Mar/2023, 18/June/2023 and 19/June/2023....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cloud Scheduler jobs by following this documentation on [creating a Cloud Scheduler job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler#create_job). Please make sure to follow the proper [cron job format](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules#cron_job_format).

I also found this [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) link wherein you can easily create a cron job. Examples below are based on the dates that you provided:

- [`0 0 13 3 *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_13_3_*) - 13/Mar/2023
- [`0 0 18 6 *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_18_6_*) - 18/June/2023
- [`0 0 19 6 *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_19_6_*) - 19/June/2023

If you have multiple schedules that won't fall on the same time/month/day, you need to create a separate job as the cron job will read the schedule continuously. For example, if you merge the months and dates altogether in a single schedule:

`0 0 13,18,19 3,6 *`

This would be read by Cloud Scheduler as:

```
At 00:00 on day-of-month 13, 18, and 19 in March and June.
next at 2023-03-13 00:00:00
then at 2023-03-18 00:00:00
then at 2023-03-19 00:00:00
then at 2023-06-13 00:00:00
then at 2023-06-18 00:00:00
```

Meaning that your job will be executed on the dates that you did not specify above.

You can merge time/month/date like this:

- [`0 0 13 3 *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_13_3_*) - 13/Mar/2023
- [`0 0 18,19 6 *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_18,19_6_*) - 18 and 19/June/2023

Comment: How do I merge this 3 dates together?